# Linking a docker container a subdirectory of another one

Tags: docker, networking, subdomain, microservices

I am trying to setup multiple docker containers that can be accessed through one main container.

For example:
`http://localhost:80` is the main container
`http://localhost:80/site1` is a separate container
`http://localhost:80/site2` is a separate container again

I know that the `--link` flag has been deprecated and the new way of doing things is by using the `--network` flag.

When I use the `--link` (for testing) I see an entry of the container I am linking to in the hosts file. That is where I am stuck.

So I would like to set the above scenario up using the docker --networking option.

Usage case: `/Site1` might be the admin area or member to a website, but I would like to have them in separate containers so I can maintain them easier.

The containers are apache2 based, but if possible would like to refrain from editing any config files (but I can if I need to)

**How would I go about that?**

Answer (score 5):

As far as I know there is no way that docker routes HTTP requests to one or the other container. You can only map a port from your host to one container.

What you will need is to run a reverse proxy (e.g. nginx) as your main container that then routes the request to the appropriate container.

---

Here an example how to set it up

### site1/Dockerfile

```
FROM node:6.11
WORKDIR /site1
COPY site1.js .
CMD node site1.js
EXPOSE 80
```

### site1/site1.js

```
var http = require("http");

http.createServer(function (request, response) {
   response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
   response.end('Hello World 1\n');
}).listen(80);
```

### site2/Dockerfile

```
FROM node:6.11
WORKDIR /site2
COPY site2.js .
CMD node site2.js
EXPOSE 80
```

### site2/site2.js

```
var http = require("http");

http.createServer(function (request, response) {
   response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
   response.end('Hello World 2\n');
}).listen(80);
```

### node-proxy/default.conf

```
server {
    listen 80;

    # ~* makes the /site1 case insensitive
    location ~* /site1 {
        # Nginx can access the container by the service name
        # provided in the docker-compose.yml file.
        proxy_pass http://node-site1;
    }

    location ~* /site2 {
        proxy_pass http://node-site2;
    }

    # Anything that didn't match the patterns above goes here
    location / {
        # proxy_pass http://some other container
        return 500;
    }
}
```

### docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3"
services:

  # reverse proxy
  node-proxy:
    image: nginx
    restart : always
    # maps config file into the proxy container
    volumes:
      - ./node-proxy/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
    ports:
      - 80:80
    links:
      - node-site1
      - node-site2

  # first site
  node-site1:
    build:  ./site1
    restart: always

  # second site
  node-site2:
    build:  ./site2
    restart: always
```

To start the reverse proxy and both sites enter in the root of this folder `docker-compose up -d` and check with `docker ps -a` that all docker containers are running.

Afterwards you can access this two sites with http://localhost/site1 and http://localhost/site2

### Explanation

The folder site1 and site2 contains a small webserver build with nodejs. Both of them are listening on port 80. "node-proxy" contains the configuration file that tells nginx when to return which site.

Here are some links

- docker-compose: https://docs.docker.com/compose/overview/
- nginx reverse proxy: https://www.nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/reverse-proxy/

Comment: can you please share a link to a tutorial or something that shows how to do it via reverse proxy ?

Comment: @SaadBinShahid I added a description how to set it up

Answer (score 0):

You should use volumes so you will set it in `docker-compose.yml` like this

```
version: '3.2'
services:
    container1:
        volumes:
            - shared-files:/directory/files
    container2:
        volumes:
            - shared-files:/directory/files
    container3:
        volumes:
            - shared-files:/directory/files


volumes:
  shared-files:
```

Comment: Ok I am relatively new to docker so I got to look into how to use those.

Comment: Ok great, glad to help. Volumes is an out of the box feature of docker to create and sync a file/directory path between containers

Comment: Does this allow me to create the subdirectory setup I described above and browse to the different containers? or is only to link to files directly?

Comment: Yes it does allow you to create the subdirectory setup

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance here, but I get an error saying that `container1 Additional property container1 is not allowed` is container1 meant to be a placeholder? - I have created a volume

Comment: `container1` is a service. YOu should put your image and build under it

Comment: With this configuration you can share files between multiple docker containers. (e.g. configuration files) I think what @JeffKranenburg wants is to have one ip endpoint that returns content from multiple webservers.

Comment: @Mathias yeah that was the idea. Still looking into this as I don’t have a ideal solution yet